# Material UI doesn't support colored text on multiline textfield (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

So I am trying to use the material ui library in a react app. I have found that seemingly the styling of the colored text doesnt work for multiline textfields. Look at this example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ListContact from './ListContact';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import Button from './Button';
import {orange500, blue500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';




const styles = {
  textInput: {
    marginRight: '10px',
    color: orange500,
    // #F3C677
  },
  textInputInput: {
    color: orange500,
    // #F3C677
  },
};





class ContactsPage extends Component {

    {/*.......*/}


                  <TextField
                    hintText="notes"
                    onChange={(e)=>this.setState({notes: e.target.value })}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    inputStyle={styles.textInputInput}
                    multiLine={true}
                    rows={2}
                    /><br/>


    {/*.......*/}
```

So the above doesn't properly style the textfield text color. However if I get rid of the multiLine and rows attributes it works correctly (either with the hex color or the color supplied by the material UI library). This is very frustrating for me as it breaks the style I was aiming at. If anyone knows a fix for this I would really appreciate it. I think there might not be however. If you go to http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field you will notice that they have very not included an example of a multiline with styled background text color, although they have almost every other example. Hmm.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field):

```
inputStyle:
```

> Override the inline-styles of the TextField's input element.
>
> **When multiLine is false:** define the style of the input element.
>
> **When multiLine is true:** define the style of the container of the textarea.

```
textareaStyle:
```

> Override the inline-styles of the TextField's textarea element. The
>   TextField use either a textarea or an input, **this property has
>   effects only when multiLine is true.**

So you need to use `textareaStyle` for styling of text when **multiline is true**, like this:

```
<TextField
    rows={2}
    hintText="notes"
    multiLine={true}
    style={styles.textInput}
    textareaStyle={styles.textInputInput}
    onChange={(e)=>this.setState({notes: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to check back. This definitely solved the problem :D. I had a bit of trouble as this wasn't made clear (for me anyway) in the examples online. I must have missed it in the docs. Thank you very much!

Comment: textareaStyle is no longer a property of TextField

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by using `inputProps` as shown in the [docs here for MUI v.5](https://mui.com/api/text-field/#props).

```
<TextField
  multiline
  inputProps={{ style: { color: "red" } }}
  /* ... */
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is the inputProps property in conjunction with my global css file:

```
inputProps={{
  className: 'a-class-with-black-text-set-as-important'
}}
```

Comment: Thanks @ian. This works in Material-UI 4.x